# Graph lines with points at the ends

Tags: plotting

I want to graph ten lines (of a single color) with points at the ends. The points are "cells" and the lines are "veins". I have tried it as follows.

```
ListPlot[Flatten[Table[{i - 1, j/149}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 10}], 1]];

Graphics[ListPlot[Table[{i - 1, j/149}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 10}]]];

Graphics[ListLinePlot[Table[{{0, j/149}, {1, j/149}}, {j, 1, 10}]]];
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = Transpose @ Table[{i - 1, j/149}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 10}];

Show[ListPlot[data, Joined -> #, PlotStyle -> Blue] & /@ {True, False}]
```

[image]

Also

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[Medium], Point /@ data}]

ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Medium]]]

Graphics[{Blue, Line@data, PointSize[Medium], Point /@ data}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

all give the same picture.

You can also use `PlotMarkers` to add  the points:

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotMarkers -> {"●", 14}]
```

or

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotMarkers -> {"●", 14}]
```